# Implementing custom video for broadcasting under AWS chime Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-chime-sdk

We need to broadcast video using custom video processing from our camera source to other attendees under kotlin code level.

We followed the given [documentation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-android/blob/master/guides/custom_video.md) but the camera video is showing black screen when the custom source is passed to the audioVideo.startLocalVideo

```
val myVideoProcessor = MyVideoProcessor()
// Add processor as sink to camera capture source
cameraCaptureSource.addVideoSink(myVideoProcessor)

// Use video processor as source to transmitted video
audioVideo.startLocalVideo(myVideoProcessor)
```

Our expected result is to integrate a filter from the camera source so that it get broadcasted to viewers where they will see the filtered video rather than the plain camera view.